# Trying to perform an operation on all sub arrays inside a numpy array without using a for (or similar) loops

Tags: python, function, loops, numpy

I have numpy arrays of following form:

```
rand_pos = [[1,2,2],[2,3,4],[1,2,5],[3,2,1]...]  #here, total subarrays = 900    
gal_pos = [[2,3,4],[56,6,64],[34,45,65]...]      #here, total subarrays ~ 10^6
```

Right now, my program picks out one sublist from rand_pos to do the following operations:

```
pos2=np.array(rand_pos[0])
dist_xyz = np.subtract(pos2,gal_pos)            
dist_square_xyz = np.square(dist_xyz)
axis = 1
dist_square_sum = dist_square_xyz.sum(axis)
dist_sqrt = np.sqrt(dist_square_sum)
list_gal_dist_in_sphere = dist_sqrt[abs(dist_sqrt) <=radius]
gal_number = len(list_gal_dist_in_sphere)
```

How can I send all the sublists from rand_pos and do this operation on all of them? I know I can loop over the rand_pos, sending one sublist at a time but is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I think `len(dist_sqrt[abs(dist_sqrt) <=radius]` might be better spelt `np.count_nonzero(abs(dist_sqrt) <= radius)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html). To see that it works, lets rewrite your method as a function with an explicit for loop:

```
def count_neighbours(arr1, arr2, rad):
    rad2 = rad * rad
    ret = np.empty((len(arr1),), dtype=np.intp)
    for j, point in enumerate(arr1):
        delta = point - arr2
        delta *= delta
        dist2 = np.sum(delta, axis=1)
        ret[j] = np.count_nonzero(dist2 <= rad2)
    return ret
```

If we now make up some test data:

```
rand_pos = np.random.rand(900, 3)
gal_pos = np.random.rand(1e5, 3) # 10x smaller than OP's data set
```

We can test both approaches:

```
>>> from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
>>> gal_tree = cKDTree(gal_pos)
>>> np.all(np.equal(count_neighbours(rand_pos, gal_pos, 0.1),
...                 [len(x) for x in gal_tree.query_ball_point(rand_pos, 0.1)]))
True
```

And time them:

```
In [13]: %timeit count_neighbours(rand_pos, gal_pos, 0.1)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.59 s per loop

In [14]: %timeit [len(x) for x in gal_tree.query_ball_point(rand_pos, 0.1)]
1 loops, best of 3: 194 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit cKDTree(gal_pos)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.7 ms per loop
```

Even for your real `gal_pos` shape, it finishes relatively quick:

```
In [16]: gal_pos = np.random.rand(1e6, 3)

In [17]: gal_tree = cKDTree(gal_pos)

In [18]: %timeit cKDTree(gal_pos)
1 loops, best of 3: 274 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit [len(x) for x in gal_tree.query_ball_point(rand_pos, 0.1)]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.22 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure rand_pos is a 2D array by checking that `rand_pos.dtype` are floats.

Then you can use `cdist`:

```
import numpy as np
XA = np.array([[0.8, 0., 1.], [0., -0.62, 1.],[0.8, 0., 1.]])
XB = np.array([[0.8, 0., 1.]])
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
Y = cdist(XA, XB, 'euclidean')
print(Y)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.        ]
 [ 1.01212647]
 [ 0.        ]]
```

Comment: XB here is a one element array. This is unlike my arrays. gal_pos is an array of shape (1134789,3) and rand1 is an array of shape (900,3).

Comment: cdist gives me a memory error when I feed in gal_pos and rand_pos (rand1 = rand_pos in comment above) to it...although it works fantastic with small arrays.

Comment: If you don't have enough memory, then loop over the smaller array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array broadcasting to calculate all the deltas at once:

```
diffs = rand_pos[np.newaxis,:,:] - gal_pos[:,np.newaxis,:]
```

```
array([[[ -1,  -1,  -2],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [ -1,  -1,   1],
        [  1,  -1,  -3]],

       [[-55,  -4, -62],
        [-54,  -3, -60],
        [-55,  -4, -59],
        [-53,  -4, -63]],

       [[-33, -43, -63],
        [-32, -42, -61],
        [-33, -43, -60],
        [-31, -43, -64]]])
```

Then sum the squares in the last axis (the one containing x, y, z):

```
dists = np.sqrt(np.square(diffs).sum(-1))
```

```
array([[  2.44948974,   0.        ,   1.73205081,   3.31662479],
       [ 82.97590012,  80.77747211,  80.75890044,  82.42572414],
       [ 83.108363  ,  80.67837381,  80.85790005,  83.10234654]])
```

gives an array where the first axis is the point selected from `gal` and the second is that from `rand`

Now you just want to count the number more than the radius (assumed to be `5`) in the vertical axis:

```
gal_numbers = (dists <= radius).sum(0)
```

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1])
```

---

Note that `diffs.shape()` will be `(900, 10^6, 3)` for your example, which is about 10GiB of memory

Comment: It gives me a memory error. Note that the shape of my rand_pos and gal_pos are: (900,3) and (1134789,3)

Comment: How can I avoid this memory problem (I do not need to store diffs)? Btw, just saw your edit about memory.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar: Go for a middle ground of your solution (use one entry of `rand` at once) and my solution (use all entries at a time), by taking say every 15 entries of `rand` (using `np.array_split`)